# Brown-Henneaux Boundary Conditions

Tags: general-relativity, boundary-conditions, ads-cft

I am trying to reproduce the Brown-Henneaux boundary conditions stated in this paper ([http://srv2.fis.puc.cl/~mbanados/Cursos/TopicosRelatividadAvanzada/BrownHenneaux.pdf](http://srv2.fis.puc.cl/%7Embanados/Cursos/TopicosRelatividadAvanzada/BrownHenneaux.pdf)).

The paper constructs a set of asymptotically $AdS_3$ metrics and the identifications of $AdS_3$ given by metric (4.2) should belong to this set, since it is locally $AdS$ everywhere. We also want that the asymptotic symmetry group (ASG) of $AdS$ is contained in the ASG of this set of metrics. Therefore if we act on the metric (4.2) with Killing vectors of $AdS_3$ we should get a metric with coefficients given as (4.3) and (4.4).

That's where I got stuck. To do that, I should use the symmetries of the metric (2.1), since (2.1) and (4.2) look alike as $r\to\infty$. I found the Killing vectors of (2.1): The rotations/boosts in $\mathbb{R}^{2,2}$ are the symmetry group of $AdS_3$, so I mapped them under the coordinate transformation from the embedding coordinates to hyper-polar coordinates (coordinates in (2.1)).

By acting with these vectors on metric (4.2) I should get (4.3) and (4.4) but I keep getting terms of order $r^4$ etc. Is something wrong with my strategy?

For example, take metric $ds^2=-du^2-dv^2+dx^2+dy^2$, then the coordinate transformation is defined by

$$ u=R\left(1+\frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)^{1/2}\cos\frac{t}{R} $$
$$ v=R\left(1+\frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)^{1/2}\sin\frac{t}{R} $$
$$ x=R\cos\phi $$
$$ y=R\sin\phi $$

when acting on (4.2) with $$J_{02}=-r\left(1+\frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)^{1/2}\sin\frac{t}{R}\cos\phi-Rr\left(1+\frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)^{1/2}\cos\frac{t}{R}\sin\phi+\left[\frac{r^2}{R}\left(1+\frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)^{-1/2}+R\left(1+\frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)^{1/2}\right]\cos\frac{t}{R}\cos\phi$$

I calculate
$$ \mathcal{L}_{J_{02}}g_{tt}=J_{02}^r\partial_rg_{tt}+2(\partial_t J_{02}^tg_{tt}+\partial_t J_{02}^\phi g_{\phi t})$$

and only the term $\partial_t J_{02}^tg_{tt}$ gives a term of $\mathcal{O}(r^4)$, so it doesn't cancel out.

Any reference that you can give, or an example about what to do would be great.

Comment: Permalink  to avoid link rot: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01211590

Comment: Thanks, but that's the same paper.

Comment: Qmechanic's link is there in case the link you provide in the post breaks at some point. Something you might find [helpful](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.08616). This is a much cleaner setup and derivation in my opinion.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you, @Richard Myers. It seems this paper is on finding asymptotic charges given the fall-off conditions, right? I want to derive the fall-off conditions.

Comment: @Cstruct This paper gives the charges given that the pullback of the metric to the boundary is fixed. To see how this works you may wish to look up the Fefferman-Graham expansion. In 3D GR this expansion truncates (giving the falloff). See also the paper by Banados finding the general solution to GR in 3D subject to asymptotic AdS3 boundary conditions.

Comment: @Richard Myers Thank you for perfect recommendations. I suppose you mean the BTZ black hole paper?

Comment: @Cstruct [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9901148.pdf).

Comment: @Richard Myers Thank you very much, you have been a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found my mistake. I am glad to report that my approach was correct but I did a mistake while transforming Killing vectors of AdS from the embedding coordinates to the static (hyper-polar) coordinates.

For people, who may have the same issue, let me write the correct transformation of $J_{02}=x\partial_u+u\partial_x$:

$$
J_{02}=R\left(1+\frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)^{1/2}\sin \frac{t}{R} \cos\phi \,\partial_r + r\left(1+\frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)^{-1/2}\cos \frac{t}{R} \cos\phi \,\partial_t - \frac{R}{r} \left(1+\frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)^{1/2}\sin \frac{t}{R} \sin\phi \,\partial_\phi
$$

Everything is working fine now.